# VBA Error: Compile error in hidden module

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, compiler-errors

I have an Excel File which I've designed to simplify a process at my workplace (with our customers)

One of the macro's is matching data between two different tabs, performing some calculations, and highlighting cells pink where an error has been found to highlight this to the end user. Most of this is done inside an array for speed (there can be quite a large volume of data)

This macro as well as all the other macros on this workbook are working perfectly well on my PC as well as my colleagues.

However, upon sending this file to some of our customers - they have reported having an issue upon running the macro I mentioned above. They have shared the below message (link below):

'Compile Error in hidden module: .............
This error commonly occurs when code is incompatible with the version, platform, or architecture of this application.

I've read this probably has to do with 32 bit vs 64 bit versions of Windows and that I might need to alter my code to account for this. However, I'm not using any declare statements which call an API, and I'm also not using any Long variables which refer to Pointers or Handlers - so I'm a bit confused what might be causing this issue.

Please could somebody help me figure out what might be causing this error message on other PC's when the code works okay for me?

```
Sub RefreshData()


    
    'Set Variables
    
    Dim fd As Worksheet
    Dim ld As Worksheet
    Dim OrN As Worksheet
    Dim RF As Worksheet
    
    Set fd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feeder Data")
    Set ld = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Live Data")
    Set OrN = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Order Numbers")
    Set RF = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("reference")
    
    Dim PeriodReturnRange As Range
    Dim YearReturnRange As Range
    Dim DateLookUpRange As Range
    
    Set PeriodReturnRange = RF.Range("K3:K200")
    Set YearReturnRange = RF.Range("I3:I200")
    Set DateLookUpRange = RF.Range("J3:J200")
    
    Dim fdArray() As String
    Dim ldArray() As String
    Dim OrNArray() As String
    Dim ldArray2() As String
    
      '' 1) Set the size of the Feeder Data Array
    On Error GoTo ErrorMsgfd
    ReDim Preserve fdArray(6 To fd.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 3 To 14)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    '' 2) Set size of Live Data Array
    On Error GoTo ErrorMsgld
    ReDim Preserve ldArray(10 To ld.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 2 To 28)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    '' 3) Set Size of Order Number Array
    On Error GoTo ErrorMsgOrN
    ReDim Preserve OrNArray(8 To OrN.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 8 To 10)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    
    ''4) Set size of second Order Number to get info needed for saving calculation
    On Error GoTo ErrorMsgld
    ReDim Preserve ldArray2(10 To ld.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 14 To 22)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    On Error GoTo PasswordErrorMsg
    ld.Unprotect "password1234"
    fd.Unprotect "password1234"
    On Error GoTo 0
    
         With Application
                    .ScreenUpdating = False
                    .EnableEvents = False
                    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        End With
        
    On Error Resume Next
    ld.ShowAllData
    fd.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0


    ''''Perform Worksheet Clearing and copy formatting down to row 5500
    
       With ld
            .Range("E4").Copy
            .Range("B10:B5500").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .Range("G10:G5500").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .Range("J10:J5500").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .Range("O10:P5500").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .Range("S10:S5500").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .Range("Z10:Z5500").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .Range("AA10:AA5500").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            
            .Range("F4").Copy
            .Range("C10:F5500").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .Range("I10:I5500").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .Range("K10:N5500").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .Range("Q10:R5500").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .Range("T10:V5500").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .Range("AA10:AB5500").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            
            .Range("G4").Copy
            .Range("H10:H5500").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .Range("W10:Y5500").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            
            .Range("C10:F5500").ClearContents
            .Range("I10:I5500").ClearContents
            .Range("K10:N5500").ClearContents
            .Range("Q10:R5500").ClearContents
            .Range("T10:V5500").ClearContents
            .Range("AA10:AB5500").ClearContents
        End With

    
    
    
    '''''''Populate Arrays
    
    ''4) Populate Feeder Data Array with the data
    
    For A = 6 To fd.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For B = 3 To 14
            fdArray(A, B) = Trim(fd.Cells(A, B))
        Next B
    Next A
    
    ''5) Populate Live Data Array
    
    For A = 10 To ld.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For B = 2 To 28
            ldArray(A, B) = Trim(ld.Cells(A, B))
        Next B
    Next A
    
    '' 6) Populate Order Number Array
    
    For A = 8 To OrN.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For B = 8 To 10
        OrNArray(A, B) = Trim(OrN.Cells(A, B))
        Next B
    Next A
    

    
    
    ''''''''' Match the values between Live Data and Feeder Data arrays (still not transferring back to worksheet)
    
    Dim LookUp1 As String
    Dim LookUp2 As String
    Dim LookUp3 As String
    
    For A = 10 To UBound(ldArray)
    
        LookUp1 = ldArray(A, 2)
        LookUp2 = ldArray(A, 7)
        
        
             On Error Resume Next
                ldArray(A, 11) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(CLng(CDate(ld.Range("J" & A).Value)), DateLookUpRange, PeriodReturnRange)
                ldArray(A, 22) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(CLng(CDate(ld.Range("J" & A).Value)), DateLookUpRange, YearReturnRange)
                On Error GoTo 0
                
    
            For B = 6 To UBound(fdArray)
        
        
                If fdArray(B, 3) = LookUp1 And fdArray(B, 9) = LookUp2 Then
                
                On Error Resume Next
                ''Calculation 1
                    If fd.Range("H" & B).Value = "ABC" Then
                    ldArray(A, 28) = fd.Range("N" & B).Value * (ld.Range("Z" & A).Value / 1000)
                    Else
                    ldArray(A, 28) = fd.Range("N" & B).Value * (ld.Range("Z" & A).Value / 100)
                End If
               
            
                ''Calculation 2
                ldArray(A, 17) = fd.Range("K" & B).Value - (ld.Range("O" & A).Value * fd.Range("L" & B).Value) - (ld.Range("P" & A).Value * fd.Range("M" & B).Value)
                ''Calculation 3
                ldArray(A, 18) = (ld.Range("O" & A).Value * fd.Range("L" & B).Value) + (ld.Range("P" & A).Value * fd.Range("M" & B).Value)
                On Error GoTo 0
                
                ''''''''Lookup results
                
                'Result 1
                ldArray(A, 3) = fdArray(B, 4)
                'Result 2
                ldArray(A, 4) = fdArray(B, 5)
                'Result 3
                ldArray(A, 5) = fdArray(B, 6)
                'Result 4
                ldArray(A, 6) = fdArray(B, 7)
                'Result 5
                ldArray(A, 9) = fdArray(B, 8)
                'Result 6
                ldArray(A, 13) = fdArray(B, 10)
                'Result 7
                ldArray(A, 14) = fdArray(B, 11)
                'Result 8
                ldArray(A, 20) = fdArray(B, 12)
                'Result 9
                ldArray(A, 21) = fdArray(B, 13)
                'Result 10
                ldArray(A, 27) = fdArray(B, 14)
                
                Exit For
                End If
               
            Next B
            
            ''Check for blanks, highlight that there has been an error if found
            If ldArray(A, 4) = "" Or ldArray(A, 5) = "" Then
                ld.Range("B" & A).Interior.Color = RGB(253, 211, 211)
                ld.Range("G" & A).Interior.Color = RGB(253, 211, 211)
            End If
            
          ''Check for blanks, highlight that there has been an error if found
            If ldArray(A, 11) = "" Or ldArray(A, 22) = "" Then
                ld.Range("J" & A).Interior.Color = RGB(253, 211, 211)
            End If
        
        
    Next A
    
    
    ''''Run a second loop between live data and order numbers, to match relevant order numbers
    
    For A = 10 To UBound(ldArray)
    
        LookUp1 = ldArray(A, 7)
        LookUp2 = ldArray(A, 5)
    
                    
        For C = 8 To UBound(OrNArray)
        
                ''check if a particular special value was found and return matched result to array if it was, and ignore second lookup value
            
                If LookUp1 = "xxx" And OrNArray(C, 9) = "xxx" Then
                            ldArray(A, 12) = OrNArray(C, 10)
                            
                ''IF special value not found, test against both lookup values''
                        
                Else
                        
                        If OrNArray(C, 9) = LookUp1 And OrNArray(C, 8) = LookUp2 Then
                                ldArray(A, 12) = OrNArray(C, 10)
                
                                Exit For
                        End If
                End If
        
        Next C
        
        
            If ldArray(A, 12) = "" Then
                ld.Range("L" & A).Interior.Color = RGB(253, 211, 211)
            End If
    
    Next A
    
    

    ''7) Transfer the matched arrays to the Worksheet
    
    ld.Range("B10", ActiveCell.Offset(UBound(ldArray, 1) - 10, UBound(ldArray, 2) - 23)).Value = ldArray
    
      
      ''''''''''Load second live data Array containing only relevant columns'''''''
    
    For A = 10 To ld.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For B = 14 To 22
            ldArray2(A, B) = ld.Cells(A, B)
        Next B
    Next A
    
    
    
    
    ''''''''''''Loop to check if a special condition has been met and color if needed'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    For A = 10 To UBound(ldArray2)

       With ld.Rows(A)
                  
            If ldArray2(A, 19) = "" And ldArray2(A, 14) = ldArray2(A, 17) And _
              Application.CountIfs(ld.Range("D10:D" & A), .Columns("D").Value, ld.Range("V10:V" & A), .Columns("V").Value, ld.Range("K10:K" & A), .Columns("K").Value) > 1 Then
                  
               .Columns("S").Interior.Color = RGB(253, 211, 211)
     
            
            End If
            
       End With
     
     Next A
    
     
     
    Erase fdArray
    Erase ldArray
    Erase OrNArray
    Erase ldArray2

    
   '''reset formatting of columns correctly, and unlock editable columns
    
    
    With ld
        .Range("B10:B5500").Locked = False
        .Range("G10:H5500").Locked = False
        .Range("J10:J5500").Locked = False
        .Range("W10:Z5500").Locked = False
        .Range("S10:S5500").Locked = False
        .Range("O10:P5500").Locked = False
        .Range("L10:L10000").NumberFormat = "@"
        .Range("E10:E10000").NumberFormat = "@"
        .Range("Q10:Q10000").NumberFormat = "0.00"
        .Range("Z10:AB10000").NumberFormat = "0.00"
    End With
    
    
    '''array is being sent as text - this line required to make data format correctly - not sure why!
 
    ld.Range("B10:AB5500").Select
    Selection.Value = Selection.Value
    
    
    ld.Range("B10").Select
    
    On Error GoTo PasswordErrorMsg
    ld.Protect "password1234", AllowFiltering:=True
    fd.Protect "password1234", AllowFiltering:=True
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    
       With Application
                    .ScreenUpdating = True
                    .EnableEvents = True
                    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        End With
      
      Exit Sub
      
      
ErrorMsgfd:
  MsgBox "No Data has been entered into the Feeder Data!", vbCritical, "Cannot Update"
  Exit Sub
  
ErrorMsgld:
  MsgBox "No Data has been entered into the Live Data!", vbCritical, "Cannot Update"
  Exit Sub
  
ErrorMsgOrN:
  MsgBox "No Data has been entered into the Order Numbers!", vbCritical, "Cannot Update"
  Exit Sub
  
PasswordErrorMsg:
   MsgBox "An incorrect password has been entered for this worksheet. Please change the password to the agreed text to continue!", vbCritical, "Incorrect Password!!"
    

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you have some paid addin, for which you did not pay? Sometimes, bad VBA developers, that want money for their time and efforts leave these tricks somehow. Anyway, in order to check go to the libraries and see the available libraries. There should not be anything "missing". And btw, the code above compiles quite ok on my machine.

Comment: Are you protecting the VBA project from viewing before sending to your clients?

Comment: @Vityata - in the VB Editor, if I go to Tools -> references -> I scroll through Libraries and nothing is available under 'missing'. But this is expected since the Code is working fine for me. Are you saying it is possible the customer might have a 'missing' library on their PC?

Comment: @StruanHenderson - it is an option that I would have check.

Comment: @TimWilliams; yes I protect the code before sending to Clients. I don't want the VB Editor to open when an error occurs because the client would have access to the code. Is it possible me protecting the code is causing an issue? If so, why would they see it on their machine, when the code works okay on my machine?

Comment: @StruanHenderson Protecting the project should not cause an issue. It is often times challenging to trouble shoot why it the vba is not working on a specific machine if you are not on that machine. You can drop a couple of information point in your vba and error handle to set message box to say "Error happened here" so when your client gets the error they can tell you the message says this.

Comment: You'll need to send then an unprotected version or they won't be able to tell you where the problem is.  Or get on a Zoom and have them share their screen so you can trouble-shoot.

Comment: Okay thanks both. I take it then that there is nothing obvious in the code I've written that should cause issues across machines using different versions of Windows or Excel? I was reading into the win64 compilation constants etc and getting a bit worried......

Comment: I don't see anything there which could trigger 32bit/64bit problems

Comment: Okay. I'll just hope it is an anomaly for now I think. I've also heard some Norton anti-virus software's can cause issues, versions of Adobe PDF software. As you say, without sending an unlocked file to the customer, it will be hard to pin-point the problem. I'm a bit reluctant to do that to be honest - I'd rather not share the exact code with them, and not sure they'd know what to do in terms of sending me evidence of the issue